# Can boost:asio io_service.run() be called more than once in a loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I´m builing an asynchronous client communications class using `boost::asio`.

In my design I have a class (`AsioThread`) and a main run method that is started as an independent thread. Here is the class method code:

```
void AsioThread::Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            transactionMutex.lock();

            switch (asioState)
            {
                case (AsioStateType::Connect): // Start a connection
                {
                    std::string address = currentCommand.arguments["address"];
                    std::string port = currentCommand.arguments["port"];

                    asioState = AsioStateType::ConnectWait;

                    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;

                    if (currentEndPoints == end)
                    {
                        boost::asio::io_service ios;
                        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);
                        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
                        currentEndPoints = resolver.resolve(query);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentEndPoints++;
                    }

                    currentSocket->close();
                    currentSocket->async_connect(*currentEndPoints, boost::bind(&AsioThread::ConnectHandler, this, _1));    
                    break;
                }

                case (AsioStateType::ConnectResponse): // Receive connection welcome message
                {
                    asioState = AsioStateType::ConnectResponseWait;
                    currentSocket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(boost::asio::buffer(rxBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)), 0, boost::bind(&AsioThread::ReceiveDataHandler, this, _1, _2));   
                    break;
                }
            }

            transactionMutex.unlock();

            ioService.run();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }
    }
```

With this code, the callbacks are never called. If I put ioService.run() just after the async_connect or async_receive line, it is called for the connection - not for the message receive. Also if I add debug lines like:

```
`std::cout << "I´m here " << std::endl´
```

sometimes the callbacks are called, depending on the place I put this debug code.

Seens to me that I´m wrong using `ioService.run()`. Note that it is called on every loop pass (10 times a second).

The mutex is used to control other threads write access to `asioState` - other threads commands this main loop actions through messages passed using this member variable.

Help appreciated to find out a way what´s wrong here...

Comment: this isn't the way to use asio. Have a read of the examples in the documentation. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/async_client.cpp

Comment: You mean there is only one way to use asio??

Comment: No, there are a few ways, but servicing the io service from a thread or thread pool is a specific way of using it and there is a correct idiom for it. You need to create a work object in order to keep the io service from stopping. When you want your worker thread(s) to stop, call stop() on the io service.

Comment: Better now... Sending the manual link and saying "that´s not the way to do it" neither answers the question nor help very much... Anyway I´m building the `work` object but I´m getting problems with exceptions, but I´m moving on... Thanks to you and jamn...

Comment: This usage seems a bit awkward to me and may quickly become complicated.  A single asynchronous commands is initiated, then essentially waited on to synchronously run.  Any reason as to why synchronous operations are not used instead?  Is the goal for each asynchronous chain to be short lived and potentially transitioning state, and also allow for external threads to transition state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `io_service::run()` runs out of work, it returns. What is happening when you call `ioService.run()` after the async operation is that it lets that operation complete, then runs out of work and returns. After you queue the next operation you need to run to `io_service` to process the operations.

An alternative approach would be to have a thread that just runs `ioService::run()` after you submit a `boost::io_service::work` object to keep it alive. To handle the cases in your switch statement you can use `io_service::post()` to trigger the operation to run them inside the run handler instead of polling a state variable. When you want to shut down the thread, destroy the work object.

Comment: I did not get the point where you say "After you queue the next operation you need to run to io_service to process the operations.". I do call ioService.run() on every interaction...

Comment: if the io_service runs out of work, it will be in the `stopped()` state. You will need to `reset()` it to get it to do any more work once you have given it some work to do.